# Excel Spreadsheet Data Transform

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, transpose

I have data in a table that needs to be transformed into time-series row data.

At the moment my data is in the following columns and format:

```
GEOID, July, August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June
```

And in the rows we have the values.

And I need my data in .csv where as the columns are:

```
GEOID, Month, Value
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free Microsoft Excel add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010) to unpivot your data and get a list in tabular form.

To make the transformation, follow the description on the [MS Website](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE&fromAR=1).

1. Import the data in Power Query (Ribbon Power Query -> from Table, cursor must be somewhere in your data)
2. Select the first column (GEOID), on the Ribbon Transform, click on Unpivot Columns > Unpivot Other Columns
3. Close and load to Excel (Ribbon Home)

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: If it was the solution for you, please mark my answer as accepted, [s. help](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer as simple as `Save As` > select `CSV` as the file type?

Once saved as a CSV, edit the document in notepad or preferred text editor to check format and make further tweaks to the columns as desired.

I find TextPad to very powerful. Try utilizing the find and replace feature in TextPad to find commas and replace them with returns(new line) `\n`. Paste the results into Excel and your Month columns will now be in rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this would take a lot of manual editing. I believe what the OP needs is a way to do this more easily using functionality in Excel as opposed to editing the information manually within a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

If understand problem correctly, then the issues is you have 13 columns of data and want to transform it into a 2 column for use with .csv. I will use the name manager as it makes it easier to do, but everything could be done with normal formulas

Step 1> make a new tab called csv or export or other name like fy16 that makes sense. The .csv will only output 1 sheet. Save it twice. Once as a .xlsx to save all the data and formulas, then when ready for csv, select csv tab and then save as csv.

Step 2> (Formula Ribbon -> Name manager) Make 2 names

- Step=13  (Go into name manage create new, name it step, and at bottom enter in =1) 
  This is the number of months
- name Spot for the cell that has GEOID, if this was in sheet1, cell a1 it would be =Sheet1!$A$1

on the csv sheet, enter "GEOID,Month,Value" in A1 to c1

Now just need the equation for each column. This formula uses a offset formula and calculates the row and column

GEOID, I assume you need the same GEOID for each entry and not just the first one
Put in A2 and copy down the following formula

- =+OFFSET(Spot,INT((ROW()-1)/step)+1,0)

What this does is start at Spot and moves down a row every 12 times (the use of int and / step) the -1 and +1 is used to get the first cell [A2] correct

Month This will just cycle on the top row
Put in B2 qnd copy down the following formula

- =+OFFSET(Spot,0,1+MOD(ROW()-2,step))
  Same as before except moving across columns from spot instead of down rows. The Mod with step causes it to cycle

Value will be moving both down rows and across columns. Both the row and the column will be similar to the first two
Put in C2 and copy down

- =+OFFSET(Spot,1+INT((ROW()-2)/step),1+MOD(ROW()-2,step))

If you do not want to use the name manager, then use 12 where there is a step in the formula. And use the appropriate Sheet1!$A$1 reference where it is crucial to use both $