# Excel dataset manipulation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having trouble manipulating my dataset into the form I need. I have 50 spreadsheets whose data must be reorganized in a certain pattern to be correctly interpreted by a software program. For one the spreadsheets, I have the initial dataset, as well as what it should look like after being reorganized. I figure that if I can recreate the final sheet starting from the initial one, then I'll be able to use the same method on the other spreadsheets.

I have included two screenshots which I hope will illustrate the pattern and how the data should be organized:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYLOB.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHAfy.png)

The data is the same in both spreadsheets, it's only the way it's laid out that has changed.

I have color-coded a few of the rows to help illustrate the pattern, which essentially consists of flipping the highlighted portion of the row horizontally, and then rotating downwards and to the right, as if on a hinge.
I'm hoping that this can be done recursively through built in excel functions since I have little experience with VBA.

My colleague and I tried using the built in function offset but made little progress, so I'm hoping someone knows of a more efficient way of solving this.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: With only screenshots, I could be wrong, but isn't the difference between the two a simple transpose?  Select the area on `Before`; then `Copy` ; select the destination, `Paste-Special-Transpose`

Comment: you try to repivot your data in a different way. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/1121618/excel-spreadsheet-data-transform/1121648#1121648) may be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

One of the core issues is that you try to use Excel as a programming language that *processes data from A to B*; that is possible, but it is not the natural behavior of a spreadsheet. A spreadsheet is supposed to contain some *input* data, and *statically* calculate other data based on it.

There are two general approaches for your kind of processing:

1. You ignore that excel wasn't really made for processes, and write VB code that you then run a single time to execute your process.
2. You reinterpret your process to be a static layout; then you can use formulas.

I am not going into VB Macro coding; there is enough written about it, and if you have no experience, it will take you some hours (if you are clever) to master enough to do what you want (or forever, if you are not thinking logically enough - programming is for many but not for everybody).
With formulas, the approach would be to define a target area somewhere (another sheet, a sheet in a collective spreadsheet for all 50, or further down on the same sheet, wherever you like), and fill that area with appropriate formulas that use the existing data to generate the layout you want.

Assuming you put the result further down, starting in row 51.

Let's start with the transposing - you can create this by entering a formula like `=INDEX($C$4:$AC$47,COLUMN()-3,ROW()-50)`. Note that I switched the column and row arguments - I put `ROW()` in the column argument, and `COLUMN()` in the row argument; that produces the transposing. The offsets will map the current cells row and column to the source cells column and row, you might have to add or subtract a bit more, just try. Copy this formula in your whole target area (same size as the source area), and adjust the offsets to get it correct.

Next step is the 'rotating'. To rotate to the right, you need to offset the cell parameter by a further 1, 2, 3, for each row you are going down, so the adjustment would give something like `=INDEX($C$4:$AC$47,COLUMN()-3+(ROW()-51),ROW()-50)` - I added `ROW()-51` to the row argument (which contains COLUMN() because of the transposing); `ROW()-51` will be 0 for the first target row, 1 for the second row, 2 for the third, etc. If you copy this formula across the target array, it will do the 'rotating'. Play with + and - to rotate left or right, and so on. You will also need to add a `MOD(...,26) around it, to make it 'wrap'.

Once you understand these concepts you can quickly create the array of formulas that generates your target layout, and use the target layout for your programs input (or - once you are sure you are done, copy the target's values over the source area, and delete the target). Note that I did not give you the exact solution, but the input to learn to handle it yourself. You need to put some more effort in it.

This is from my experience the easiest way to learn and apply to ever-changing requirements. Again, feel free to use the VB Macro approach instead; it is more learning, but you then have a much more powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm not sure how long the $A column of numbers is.

It looks pretty easy to put into a macro, 
following your manual steps to convert it.
As I see it...

Select A$ 
Insert Column
Select $A$4
Fill down 0 to x ?
Select $C$4
[shift]+[ctrl]+[arrow right]
[shift]+[ctrl]+[arrow down]
[Ctrl]+[X] ( cut )
Paste special with Transpose option into $a$4
```

( approximate english instructions not VBA)
Then Choose Tools Macro record and assign a hot key and record then stop and save.